# Cross fromula fields from Opportunity to Quote with custom fields

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I'm trying to access some custom fields in the Quote object from Opportunity Object.
I tried to use cross formula fields to access the fields via SyncedQuote, but for some reason not all my custom fields from the Quote Object appear in the dropdown menue.

Is there any reason why only some some custom fields can be linked and others can't?

In general I want to build a VisufalForce PDF formula set up on the Opportunity Objects, for which I need data from the Quote custom fields. Is there any other possibilty to archieve that?
It is important to notice that my company doesnt have the enterprise licence, so no apex code is available. Can this be archived without?

Many Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you force it even though it doesn't show up in the creator? Manually type `Opportunity.SyncedQuote.MyCustomField__c`, either in formula or in the Visualforce page?

Comment: While typing manually i've found out that all fields who do not show up in the creater are rich text fields. I think thats the solution..
But it occured another problem: When I insert the fields (normal text fields) in my Visual Force page via Opportunity.SyncedQuote.MyCustomField__c, they do not contain any content.
What is this related to?

Comment: I don't have an org with quotes handy, sorry. My gut feel would be something with Profile/Permission sets, are the fields marked as visible to your user? It might matter, even if you're sysadmin and normally you see all. Quote is a freak object, for a long time it didn't even have a Tab, it doesn't have field history tracking... If you don't figure anything clever - consider asking at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ too. Especially if you can't code it.